# WordPress hangs on log in after migrating

Tags: php, wordpress

After trying to move WordPress from local machine to my production machine, I have done the following:

1. Import my current local database
   into production database
2. Updated my **wp-config.php** file with
   correct information
3. Went into phpmyadmin, updated
   '**siteurl**' and '**home**' with correct
   URL
4. Finally, I was able to see the
   wordpress site, and everything else
   works fine.
5. **When I try to log in, however, it
   *hangs*. I don't get error messages, or nothing..**

Here's what I did, in my attempt to fix it (unsuccessful):

1. Re-uploaded wp-login.php file.
2. clear cookies, cache

both servers are using IIS7.. any clues?

**EDIT**

One thing I noticed is that, I can't login to any php based logins.. I tried logging in phpmyadmin, but it didn't work for me.

One thing I know for sure is that, the new server doesn't recognize index.php as default document. Could that be a problem?

Comment: PHP + IIS = eek! Turn on WP_DEBUG and see what's up.

Comment: It seems to hang forever..... I don't get any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing all URLs in the database, not just the site and home on options.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change all the URLs in your SQL file to match the new installation.

Here is an example data that needs to be replaced. Make sure you find and replace all instances. You can use any text-editor with find and replace capabilities (I use Notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ usually)

Assuming you are moving from a local installation `http://localhost/example/` to `http://www.example.com/`

Step 1. replace `http://localhost/example/` by `http://www.example.com/`

Step 2. replace `localhost\\/example\\/` by `www.example.com\\/`

(This is required if you are using some  plugin which stores the data in this way like revolution slider)

Step 3. replace `http://localhost/example` by `http://www.example.com`

Step 4. replace `localhost/example` by `www.example.com`

Hope this helps.